# Wordpress/htaccess rewrite rule catching parent but not subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress site located in the root of the server.

I have a potential url structure of https://www.example.com/parks/sub1/sub2/
*sub1* and *sub2* are variable.

- / should pass on to index.php as normal
- /parks/ and /parks/sub1/ should match in the redirect.
- /parks/sub1/sub2/ matches should be ignored and passed onto Wordpress as normal. (it is a blog post)
- trailing slash should be optional (may or may not exist)

currently, this rule properly catches /parks/ and /parks/sub1/.  Unfortunately it is also catching /parks/sub1/sub2/.

> ```
> add_rewrite_rule( '^parks\/(.*)\/?', "index.php?page_id=14", "top" );
> ```

Comment: You only anchored the pattern to the beginning with `^`, but it is missing the anchoring to the end via `$`.

Comment: Your comment helped me end up at the answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different route and solved it via:

> ```
>  add_rewrite_rule( '^parks\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/?$', "index.php?page_id=14", "top" );
> ```

I'm hoping I'm not overlooking anything.